# Which currently active philosophers could be considered Wittgenstein followers?

Tags: reference-request, wittgenstein

A. C. Grayling offers the following description of currently active followings of Wittgenstein (page 129):

> The Wittgensteinians accordingly make a distinctive although relatively small group in contemporary philosophy, studying Wittgenstein's texts closely and applying his methods, with some of them refusing to take more recent developments in philosophy seriously on the grounds that they involve departures from Wittgenstein's ideas. A considerable amount has been published by these followers, ranging from exegesis to hagiography, and including some original work which has variously been controversial and stimulating.

On page 132 he mentions Janik and Toulmin's *Wittgenstein's Vienna* which might be an example of what he is referring to (or might not). I wonder which philosophers could be considered to fit the above description and are currently active.

Hence the question: *Which currently active philosophers would fit Grayling's description of Wittgenstein followers?*

---

Grayling, A. C. (2001). A Very Short Introduction. Oxford University Press.

Comment: Great question. Always those who are willing to join a cult. Came across this: https://existentialcomics.com/comic/117

Comment: how about crispin wright?

Comment: Hacker is perhaps the best known one. In [Wittgenstein's Place in Twentieth-CenturyPhilosophy](http://pdfhumanidades.com/sites/default/files/apuntes/Hacker%2C%20P.M.S.%20-%20Wittgenstein%E2%80%99s%20place%20in%20twentieth-century%20analytic%20philosophy-Blackwell%20%281996%29.pdf) he characterizes analytic post-Wittgenstein philosophy as follows:"*What, from Wittgenstein’s perspective,  were diseases  of the intellect,  to  many  of which he himself had suc­cumbed  as  a young man and which he had laboured long to extirpate,  broke out afresh in mutated, virulent forms*".

Comment: @JD: Cult? Hmph. I think you've mistaken the exit for the entrance... 

Answer (score 1):

Grayling was writing in 2001, so a number of Witttgensteinians of that time may no longer be with us. One who isn't is Bede Rundle, whose works are informed by Wittgensteinian ideas: 'Why There is Something Rather than Nothing' (2004) and the earlier Mind in Action (1997) are relevant here.

Carolyn Wilde, happily still with us, engaged deeply with Wittgenstein's ideas. Some of her work is listed at : https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Carolyn_Wilde.

Cora Diamond is a notable Wittgensteinian - a Wittgenstein scholar and a creative user of Wittgenstein's work. See for example The Realistic Spirit (Representation and Mind series): Wittgenstein, Philosophy, and the Mind (1995) and Reading Wittgenstein with Anscombe, Going On to Ethics (2019).